# pydevd trigger CMD_ADD_EXCEPTION_BREAK from runtime code

Tags: python, pycharm, pydev, remote-debugging

Using pydevd, is there a way that I can turn on & off suspending code on uncaught exceptions directly from the runtime code (rather than from the debug server), similar to how adding `pydevd.settrace()` behaves as a breakpoint?

Basically, I have a large application that uses generators and threading to process and manipulate lots of data. Because of this, manually setting breakpoints can be quite cumbersome. Currently I'll inspect the stack trace, inspect the code, and try to construct a conditional `pydevd.settrace()` that will hopefully only trigger when the offending scenario is hit. This takes a good bit of trial and error.

What I'd love to do is make (or use) a context manager and wrap the offending code like this

```
with pydevd.suspend_on_exception():
    ... code causing eventual exception ...
```

I've dug around the pydevd code, and tried (with no luck) various incantations to try to simulate what I think the remote debugger is doing. I thought the following would get me close, but no dice.

```
debugger = pydevd.get_global_debugger()
ex = debugger.add_break_on_exception('Exception', True, True, False, True)
debugger.update_after_exceptions_added([ex])
debugger.enable_tracing_in_frames_while_running_if_frame_eval()
```

(roughly based on https://github.com/fabioz/PyDev.Debugger/blob/master/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_process_net_command.py#L496)

I'm using pydevd to connect to a PyCharm remote debugging server, in case that makes a difference in the solution.

Answer (score 0):

That code seems correct for me...

i.e.: Running the code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import pydevd
    debugger = pydevd.get_global_debugger()
    ex = debugger.add_break_on_exception('Exception', True, True, False, True)
    debugger.update_after_exceptions_added([ex])
    debugger.enable_tracing_in_frames_while_running_if_frame_eval()

    def foo():
        raise Exception()

    foo()
```

does stop in the proper exception here.

Note: this is actually tested on the latest PyDev, not on PyCharm, but the behavior should be the same.